# ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Binding Resources

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I am looking for a good resource that describes very thoroughly how model binding works with ASP.NET MVC 3 (or to a lesser extent, MVC 2) and different approaches. I have not been able to find any good resources on this topic, except bits and pieces there. The information on the net is more about "how to do X" than explaining how the internals of model binding work. Any recommendations? Book recommendations are fine as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look:

ASP.NET MVC Model Binding - Part1 and Part2

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCModelBinding.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCModelBinding2.aspx

6 Tips for ASP.NET MVC Model Binding

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Custom Model Binders in MVC 3 with IModelBinder

http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/

Answer (score 1):

The Features and Foibles of ASP.NET MVC Model Binding - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx