# Custom model binding returns default values

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have created a custom Model Binder that inherits from DefaultModelBinder, and overriding the BindProperty method to set the "duration" property to 35.

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "Duration")
        {
            var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var prefix = propertyDescriptor.Name;

            SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, 35);
        }
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
```

A breakpoint in this method gets hit, and all seems well,  But when my action is hit after, my model has reverted back to giving Duration is default value of 0.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ModelType model)
    { var val = model.Duration;
      //val = 0 :(
    }
```

I'm a little stuck, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are calling the base method. Try like this:

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
{
    if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "Duration")
    {
        var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var prefix = propertyDescriptor.Name;

        SetProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, 35);
        return; // <!-- We have set the value so no need to continue any more
    }

    // This will be called for all other properties
    base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
}
```

Comment: where can I find SO or other information on custom model binding?

Comment: @Maslow, what kind of information? *Custom model binding* is a pretty broad subject.

Comment: When/Why/How? I guess most of what I was looking for is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2902871/57883

Comment: and much more of it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692964/asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding-resources