# How to specify one input model for MVC3 and the other output (result) model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, viewmodel

What should I do, when I need one ViewModel class to be **passed** to the asp-page (containing various data to display) and another Model class I need to be **submitted** (through the `form` tag) back to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the *"Other View Model"* inside the main View Model. Then bind the controls of the form to the sub-model's properties.

Action Method Signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(SubModel model) { /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Custom Model Binder to bind the Input Model based on the form generated by output model.
Check this link for more information:

http://buildstarted.com/2010/09/12/custom-model-binders-in-mvc-3-with-imodelbinder/

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Binding Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692964/asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding-resources)

Answer (score 0):

If the properties of the two view models are more or less same then the default model binder will take care else you have to go for a custom model binder.

The other options if you have to create the html fields with the names of the ViewModel properties that you are going to bind on post.