# MVC sending data from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am quite new to MVC 3.

I know how to send a strongly typed object from a Controller to a View. What I have now, is a View which contains a table/form which consists of that data.

The user can change that data whilst they're are in that View (html page).

When they click on "Save", how do I send the data from the View back to the Controller so that I can update my database.

Do I overload the Controller method so that it accepts a parameter of the model type? Can you please provide some source code.

(Please do not show code of persisting data to a database, I know how to do that part).

Thank you very much for helping me.

I would also prefer using `@Html.BeginForm()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like creating an action method made for my post data.  So let's say you have a UserViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then a UserController:

```
public class UserController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        // Create your UserViewModel with the passed in Id.  Get stuff from the db, etc...
        var userViewModel = new UserViewModel();
        // ...

        return View(userViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {
        // This is the post method.  MVC will bind the data from your
        // view's form and put that data in the UserViewModel that is sent
        // to this method.

        // Validate the data and save to the database.

        // Redirect to where the user needs to be.
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you have a form in your view already.  You'll want to make sure that the form posts the data to the correct action method.  In my example, you'd create the form like so:

```
@model UserViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "User", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
}
```

The key to all this is the model binding that MVC does.  Make use of the HTML helpers, like the Html.TextBoxFor I used.  Also, you'll notice the top line of the view code I added.  The @model tells the view you'll be sending it a UserViewModel.  Let the engine do work for you.

Edit:  Good call, did that all in Notepad, forgot a HiddenFor for the Id!

Comment: +1 was writing practically the same answer. For the view part as well, you could just use [EditorForModel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430917(v=vs.98).aspx)  along with DataAnnotations to control the output instead of manually setting up each editable property.

Comment: Great catch @nonnb!  Edited my example.

Comment: @James, I've never really done a lot with the EditorForModel, and I'm not sure how complicated his site is.  Good suggestion, though.

Comment: Also, this is a nice link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493063(v=vs.108) The input helpers are what I was using for the input fields.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if the site is complicated or not, the `EditorForModel` extension basically does what you have written in your example with one line.

Comment: Thank you very very very very very much. Your post made perfect sense! I was able to add in my user controls, send current data in to the form controls and then send them back to the Controller.

Thank you very very much! Perfect explanation, very nicely written, unambiguously explained....AWESOME. I LOVE YOU! I LOVE YOU! MWAH!

Comment: @James, right, but this was just an example.  Don't care that it might have done it on one line, it then doesn't highlight the input helpers much, or the customization he would be able to do.

Comment: @Gromer you were suggesting that using EditorForModel vs individual helpers was determined by how complicated the site was, which it doesn't. I was merely adding to your answer as the OP (and yourself) may not have known about it. Less code = easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC, the act of scraping out data from POST or GET HttpRequests is referred to as Model Binding - there are plenty of [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692964/asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding-resources) relating to this.

Out of the box, MVC will bind your Get and Post variables based on convention, e.g. a form field with the name 'FormName' will be bound back to a parameter on your controller with the same name.

Model binding also works for objects - MVC will instantiate an object for your controller, and  set the properties with the same name as your form.