# What is model binding in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is model binding in ASP.NET MVC, Why is it needed? Can someone give simple example , Can model binding be achieved by checking create strongly typed view?

Comment: Check this: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: It is needed for seperation of concerns and to make things more OOP way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Binding Resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692964/asp-net-mvc-3-model-binding-resources)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`ModelBinding` is the mechanism ASP.NET MVC uses to create strongly-typed objects (or fill primitive-type parameters) from the input stream (usually an HTTP request).

For example, consider this `Person` model:

```
public class Person
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you have some `Action` in some `Controller` that's expecting a `Person` type as a parameter:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
      public ActionResult EditPersonDetails(Person person)
      {
          // ...
      }
}
```

The `Model-Binder` is then responsible to fill that `person` parameter for you. By default it does it by consulting the `ValueProviders` collection and asking for the value of each property in the (to be bound) model.

More on Value-Providers and Model-Binders on http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/30/whatrsquos-the-difference-between-a-value-provider-and-model-binder.aspx/