# What is Kendo DataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I am looking at a piece of code written for Kendo which looks like following:

```
public ActionResult ReadEmployee([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(GetEmployees().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have few questions about it:

1. Is DataSourceRequest a kind of ActionResult?
2. Since it is used in confines of KendoUI, I am not able to understand the nature of this object in much more detail.

What is exact role of this object? Is there any documentation which explains it in details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in summary it is a model binder for Kendo.

> ModelBinding is the mechanism ASP.NET MVC uses to create strongly-typed objects (or fill primitive-type parameters) from the input stream (usually an HTTP request).

for more information check [what is modelBinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721542/what-is-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

All the paging and sorting logic that a grid provides is in that object. So you make an IQueryable and then all the paging magic happens in the ToDataSourceResult method.