# Receiving an error while passing an argument from a view to a method from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So, these are the 2 pieces of code that are causing the error.

The View:

```
...
@foreach (FinalCampaign fc in @Model)
{
   <h1>@fc.Camp.Id</h1>
   <h2>@Html.ActionLink(@fc.Camp.Name, "GoToPage", "Home", fc.Camp.Id, null)</h2>
   <p>@fc.Camp.CampaignStartDate - <font color="Blue"><u>@fc.Username</u></font></p>
   <p>@fc.Camp.Description</p>
}
```

And here is the "GotoPage" function from my controller:

```
public ActionResult GoToPage(string id)
    {
        CampaignCommentsModel ff = new CampaignCommentsModel();
        var cT = new CampaignTable(new OracleDatabase("DefaultConnection"));
        Campaign camp = cT.GetCampaignById(id);
        ...
        return View(ff);
    }
```

And this is my problem: the "id" from GotoPage (the argument) is null, it doesn't receive the value from my view.

Comment: you're using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).  Take a look at the example on the page and adjust your routeValues to look like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
 <h2>@Html.ActionLink(@fc.Camp.Name, "GoToPage", "Home", new { id = fc.Camp.Id}, null)</h2>
```

You can not pass a nested properties in this way. The default model binder can not associate such an object with a parameter in your action method.

ActionLink extension: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx

Model binding: [What is model binding in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721542/what-is-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2>@Html.ActionLink(@fc.Camp.Name, "GoToPage", "Home",new {id = fc.Camp.Id}, null)</h2>
```

See here [Actionlink method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx)