# Pass form data via Ajax to Action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to pass many values to Action in MVC but, **user** is always null.

```
var form = $('form');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Content("~/User/UpdateUser")',
        data: { user: form.serialize(), NameOfCare: care },
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "Ok") {
                document.location.href = '@Url.Content("~/User/Index")';
            }
        }
    });
```

how to pass form with many values in Ajax ?

Comment: use @Url.Action if UpdateUser is your action method. Moreover, place your action method code here.

Comment: You can use the `.param()` method to add additional data - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353093/mvc-jquery-ajax-post-returns-null/32353268#32353268). And as noted by others, it needs to be `url: '@Url.Action(...)'`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to use `@Url.Action` instead `@Url.Content` because you have to send your `form` data to a `controller` in order to process `data`.

**`.serialize` method encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.**

You should use this: `data:form.serialize() + "&NameOfCare="+care`.

On `server-side` your method should looks like this:

```
public ActionResult(UserViewModel user,string NameOfCare){

}
```

`user` object will be `filled` with your data , using [Model Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721542/what-is-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

you are sending a serialized object while it's actually a string. try below example. The action will de-serialize the string automatically.

```
        function load() {
        var dataT = $("#searchform").serialize();
        var urlx = "@Url.Action("SR15Fetch", "SR15", new { area = "SALES" })";
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: urlx,    
            data: dataT,  
            cache: false,
            success: HandellerOnSuccess,
            error: HandellerOnFailer,
            beforeSend: Ajax_beforeSend(),
            complete: Ajax_Complete(),
        });
    }
```

Comment: The question is about add an additional name/value pair (`NameOfCare: care`) to the serialized object and this does not address that at all.