# Where does mvc httppost function gets its parameters from

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm editing a code written by someone who left nearly no comments. I'm trying to find where does a parameter in a `httppost` function come from. (`ism` in this case).

```
 [HttpPost]
 [SessionCheckFilter]
 [LogFilter]
 [ValidateInput(false)]
 [ActionName("Save")]
 public ActionResult Save(StructureViewModelPOST ism){...}
```

The thing is, `StructureViewModelPOST` is only used in this function. There are no other references to it. I want to change the data in the `ism`, but I have no idea where it comes from. This function is called when someone presses the "save" or "save and close" button inside my form

```
<a class="btn btn-primary fixed-width navigation"  href="#" onclick="checkTotalValue(1);"><i class="icon-save pull-left navigation"></i>Save</a>
```

And the form is created like this inside my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Invoice", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

I realise i'm not providing you with all the information necessary to answer this quesion, but I can't just paste the whole project and I don't really know what information IS needed to answer it.

Comment: The parameter "ism" should be the form that is posted from the view. In this case it will be of the type StructureViewModelPOST.

Comment: From your form controls, from route values, from query string values, from JSON data if using an ajax post with the appropriate `contentType`. All of them send name/value pairs and it the name matches one of your property names, the `DefaultModelBinder` will bind it using various `ValueProviders`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC modelbinder works by convention, that is, it tries to match the name and id of a HTML `<input name="ThePropertyName" id="ThePropertyName"/>` element to a property in the model class accepted by the post action in the controller.

So if `StructureViewModelPOST` class has a property `string ThePropertyName { get; set; }`,
this property will be filled with the value of the matching input that has the `name="ThePropertyName"`.

There is more than one way to render this input with the correct name.

Using a ViewModel defined with the `@model` directive, and resolving the input type to be used with an editor template:

```
@model StructureViewModelPOST
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ThePropertyName)
```

Or more directly:

```
@Html.TextBox(nameof(StructureViewModelPOST.ThePropertyName), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically action parameters is bound from posted form fields

each Field Is Bound To The Corresponding Properties With The Same Name

example :

```
<input type='text' name='TotalDiscount' />
```

will be bound to ism.TotalDiscount

Check These Links

[What is model binding in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721542/what-is-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc)

and Model Binder Section Here

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios